# What should I direct cast this tablecell object to?

Tags: vb.net, dom

```
            Dim row = DirectCast(input.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement, mshtml.IHTMLTableRow)
            Dim cell = DirectCast(row.cells.item(5), mshtml.htmltabledatacellelement)
            Dim ctr = Val(cell.innertext)
```

If I do not use `directCast` on a second line the type return is indeed `mshtml.htmltabledatacellelement`. That's what I see if I hover.  However there is no such type.

So what should I cast that too?

Also I want to get the `InnerText` value of that thing whatever it is.

So what should I cast it too? How do I know that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried casting it to `HtmlElement` like:

```
Dim cell = DirectCast(row.cells.item(5), HtmlElement)
```